# MySQL replication where slave is behind LAN

Tags: mysql, networking, replication

we have this scenario where we will make circular master-master replication where one of the servers is inside local network,

the problem in the first place is to enable a company to work on its local server even if there is internet connection downtime,

how to expose this server to the Internet ?,

and is there another solution to this use case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expose your server by publicising it's IP address through a service like selfip.com. Of course, then it is open to outside attacks as well.